# Rethinkdb between with multiple keys

Tags: indexing, range, rethinkdb, reql

I've the following structrue :

```
Item {
  id string,
  title string
  tags []string,
  time int,
  parent string
}
```

What i want, `list all items with tags [tag1, tag2, ... etc] of parent "parent-1" and order by time`

So i did this

```
r.db("db").table("tb").indexCreate("allByTime", function(row){
  return row("tags").map(function(tag){
    return [row("parent"), tag, row("time")]
  })
})
```

It worked with a query like this

```
r.db("db").table("tb").between(["parent-1", "tag1", 0], ["parent-1", "tag1", <some-bigger-timestamp>], {index: "allByTime"}).orderBy(...)
```

But also i want something like this

```
r.db("db").table("tb").between(["parent-1", ["tag1", "tag2"], 0], ["parent-1", ["tag1", "tag2"], <some-bigger-timestamp>], {index: "allByTime"}).orderBy(...)
```

---

Any suggestions ?

### **NOTE ->** i don't want to use `r.filter(...)`

I've tried something like this

```
r.union(<between-query-1>, <between-query-2>, ...)
```

but i don't know what the overhead will be in large table with many between queries .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly, I don't think what you want is really possible. If you think about it, what you want is a compound index with a multi index inside of it and I don't think there's any way to express that in RethinkDB.

In this query:

```
r.db("db").table("tb")
 .between(
    ["parent-1", ["tag1", "tag2"], 0], 
    ["parent-1", ["tag1", "tag2"], <some-bigger-timestamp>], 
    {index: "allByTime"}
  )
  .orderBy(...)
```

It seems that what you want here is: all documents with a parent of `'parent1'` AND with `'tag1'` AND `'tag2'` with a timestamp BETWEEN `0` and `<some-bigger-timestamp>`. It seems that, if that is the case, then union wouldn't really work, because you can't query fields by multiple values.

**My Proposed Solution: Just use `filter`!**

In the query you had before:

```
r.db("db").table("tb")
 .between(
   ["parent-1", "tag1", 0], 
   ["parent-1", "tag1", <some-bigger-timestamp>], 
   {index: "allByTime"}
 )
 .orderBy(...)
```

You are probably narrowing down your data to a portion of your data in which you CAN use `filter`. I think the point of `filter` is that you should never use it. The point of `filter` is to use it smartly when (using a large dataset), you've already used indexes smartly (which you have). If the result of that `between` query is more than a couple of thousand, then you might have problems, but if it's not, I wouldn't worry about it. If it is, then maybe you can update your question with more about your data (how many different parents, tags, timestamps present) and what make a single document unique.

Comment: i'm also thought that it is not possible with rethinkdb, 
there are thousands of rows, and i may re-design the structure . 
thanks for your try